# In Python, how to get the values of dynamically created Entry widgets

Tags: tkinter, dynamic, widget

Python 3.8.0

I am creating a simple GUI to read/write a set of currency values from/to a file. The user could create a new currency by updating a file, and the GUI generates the Label and Entry widget accordingly.

The user can then update the values of the currencies, and the program will then write the values back to the file for use next time.

I have 3 files in the project:
`main_ar.py` - the main loop
`ar_currency_window.py` - the class for the GUI frame
`currency.py` - the list of currencies and values

The code is listed below and operates perfectly. The window is generated and creates the Labels and Entry widgets, and populates the input boxes with the corresponding values.

The currencies are held as a dictionary, with the key as the 3-letter currency code. What I now need to do is to read these values back to the dictionary so I can save them to the file.

I was struggling to find a way to link the Entry text to the currency dictionary, but using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080894/accessing-dynamically-created-tkinter-widgets) as a basis, I was able to come up with a solution.

I now maintain a separate dictionary which uses a 0-based sequence as the key (equates to the row number of the Entry widget) and holds the currency code as the value. I then loop through that, and find the currency in the original dictionary, and can then compare the values as needed.

I did try to bind the original dictionary to the Entry widget, but I could not get this to work - it didn't generate an error, just did nothing.

So, my question is: Is there a way to either bind the dictionary to the Entry widget, or a slightly less convoluted approach to the problem?

main_ar.py

```
from ar_currency_window import Currency


root = Currency()
root.grid()
root.mainloop()
print("finished")
```

ar_currency_window.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Currency(tk.Tk):

    def close_window(self):
        self.destroy()

    def save_values(self):
        for entry in self.currencyList:
            findCurrency = self.currencyList[entry]
            oldValue = self.currencies[findCurrency]
            newValue = self.entries[entry].get()

            if oldValue != newValue:
                self.currencies[findCurrency] = newValue

        print(self.currencies)

    def readCurrencies(self):
        myfile = "currency.py"
        with open(myfile) as raw_data:
            for item in raw_data:
                if ':' in item:
                    key, value = item.split(':', 1)
                    self.currencies[key] = value.strip()
                else:
                    pass  # deal with bad lines of text here
        print(self.currencies)

    def writeCurrencies(self):
        myfile = "currency.py"
        with open(myfile, 'w') as f:
            for key, value in self.currencies.items():
                f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # The Currencies and Entries strutures
        self.currencies = dict()
        self.currencyList = dict()
        self.entries=[]

        # Set the title and frame properties
        self.title("AR Currency Management")
        self.frame = ttk.Frame(self, padding=(10,10))

        # Gets the requested values of the height and width.
        windowWidth = self.winfo_reqwidth()
        windowHeight = self.winfo_reqheight()

        # Gets both half the screen width/height and window width/height
        positionRight = int(self.winfo_screenwidth() / 2 - windowWidth / 2)
        positionDown = int(self.winfo_screenheight() / 2 - windowHeight / 2)

        # Positions the window in the center of the page.
        self.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))

        # Read in the currencies from the file
        self.readCurrencies()

        # Now create the labels and entry boxes in the frame
        # We use a list to keep track of the entries, so we can reference the entered values later
        r = 0 # row counter
        for k in self.currencies:
            c_label = ttk.Label(self.frame, text=k)
            c_input = ttk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.currencies[k])
            c_input.insert(0,self.currencies[k])

            c_label.grid(column=0, row=r, sticky="W")
            c_input.grid(column=1, row=r, sticky="w")
            self.entries.append(c_input)
            self.currencyList[r]=k
            r += 1

        # Button to save the values
        btnSave = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Save Currency Values",command=self.save_values)
        btnExit = ttk.Button(self.frame, text="Close",command=self.close_window)
        btnSave.grid(column=0,row=r+1,sticky="W")
        btnExit.grid(column=0, row=r+2, sticky="W")

        self.frame.grid()
```

currency.py

```
EUR:1.14
CAD:1.13
POL:2.13
NOK:8.23
USD:0.98
OLK:3.33
PLZ:101.54
```

Many thanks
Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I solved my problem by using lists and finally figuring out StringVars!

So, the following section of code was updated:

```
for k in self.currencies:
    c_label = ttk.Label(self.frame, text=k)
    c_input = ttk.Entry(self.frame, textvariable=self.currencies[k])
    c_input.insert(0,self.currencies[k])
```

to this:

```
for k in range(len(self.currencies)):
    c_label = ttk.Label(master, text=self.currencies[k]['Code'], width=5)
    c_label.grid(column=0, row=r, sticky="W")

self.Rates.append( StringVar() )
    self.Rates[k].trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, sv=k:         
        self.validate_rate_data(name, index, mode, self.Rates[sv]))
    t = ttk.Entry(master, width=10,textvariable=self.Rates[k])
    t.insert(0, self.currencies[k]['Rate'])
    t.grid(column=1, row=r, sticky="w", padx=(10, 10))
```

The function variable_rate_data is defined as follows:

```
def validate_rate_data(self,name, index, mode, var):
    #Scan the Rates and ensure they are numeric
    try:
        f_number = float(var.get())
    except ValueError:
        print("ERROR")
```

And the Rates list is defined as `self.Rates = []`

The `StringVar` trace method is used to call the `validate_rate_date` method when the value changes in the widget. The `get()` method is then called to extract the value and I can then do the validation.